# bootstrap-select multiple, validar si la opcion seleccionada por el usuario es selected o no

Tags: jquery, symfony2

[image: Imagen boostrap-select]

Lo que busco es que, al dar click en alguna de las opciones del select, me diga si esta seleccionado o ya no esta seleccinado, cuando deselecciono una opción de las tres el siguiente código me dice que si esta seleccionado, pero en verdad lo deseleccione, y en ese caso me debería de decir que no esta seleccionado. El codigo solo funciona con la ultima opcion, osea, cuando ya solo queda una opcion seleccionada, y previamente deseleccione las dos, si funciona muy bien y me dice al seleccionar o deseleccionar si esta o no seleccionado... pero lo que busco es una forma de que cada opcion del select me diga si esta o no seleccionada. He probado muchas formas consultando y no he podido solucionarlo. Muchas gracias si pueden ayudarme.

```
 $('#sautores').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
            if ($("#sautores option[name='"+nombres+"']").prop("selected") == true) {
                  alert("Si esta seleccionado");
                } else {
                   alert("No esta seleccionado");
                }

        });
```

**EDITADO:**

Este es mi codigo, incluido el html, lo que pretendo es que al seleccionar un autor, automaticamente se completen los campos de Identificación, Ponentes, Email, Telefono, y al deseleccionar el autor se remuevan los datos que se habian agregado a los campos(Identificación, Ponentes, Email, Telefono) ojalá me puedas ayudar:

```
<script> $('#sautores').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
            var option=$('#ponen option').length;
            if(option<=3){
            var a=$('#sautores').val();
            var s = a.toString();
            var count = s.split(";").length;
            var res = s.split(";");
            if(count==2){
            var per=res[1].split(",");
            }else{
                if(count==3){
                    var per=res[2].split(",");
                }else{
                    if(count==4){
                        var per=res[3].split(",");
                    }
                }
            }
                        var nombres=per[0];
                        var iden=per[1];
                        var email=per[2];
                        var tel=per[3];
                        $("#sautores option[name='"+nombres+"']").each(function(){
                         if ($(this).prop("selected") == true) {
                                    $("#ponen").append("<option value='"+nombres+"' >"+nombres+"</option>");
                                    $("#iden").val($("#iden").val()+", "+iden);
                                    $("#email").val($("#email").val()+", "+email);
                                    $("#tel").val($("#tel").val()+", "+tel);
                                    $('#ponen').selectpicker('refresh');
                         } else {
                             alert("No esta seleccionado");
                         }
                });         
            }

        });
    </script> <div class="form-group" align="left">

<label for="autores">Autores:</label>
                         -------------------------------------------------->>>>>>>
                                                                                        <p>Si hay más autores, ingresa el código y seleccionalo, (Máx. 3 personas).</p>
                                                                                                                        <select id="sautores" class="selectpicker form-control" data-size="3" data-live-search="true" data-max-options="3" name="autores[]" multiple>
                                                                                                                            {% for personalesr in personales %}
                                                                                                                            <option value="{{personalesr.nombres}}" selected>{{personalesr.nombres}}</option>
                                                                                                                           {% for codigosr in codigos %}
                                                                                                                               {%if (personalesr.nombres != codigosr.nombres)%}
                                                                                                                              <option value=";{{codigosr.nombres}},{{codigosr.numero_documento}},{{codigosr.email}},{{codigosr.telefono}}" name="{{codigosr.nombres}}" data-tokens="{{codigosr.codigo_identificacion}}">{{codigosr.nombres}}</option>
                                                                                                                              {%endif%}
                                                                                                                          {% endfor %}
                                                                                                                          {% endfor %}
                                                                                                                        </select>

                                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                                                                                                              <label for="iden">Identificación:</label>
                                                                                                              {% for personalesr in personales %}
                                                                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{personalesr.numero_documento}}" name="iden" id="iden" readonly>
                                                                                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                                                                                                              <label for="ponen">Ponentes:</label>
                                                                                                              <p>(Máx. 2 personas).</p>
                                                                                                                        <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="ponen[]" data-max-options="2" required id="ponen" multiple>
                                                                                                                    <option disabled value=" ">Seleccione ponentes...</option>
                                                                                                                        {% for personalesr in personales %}
                                                                                                                        <option value="{{personalesr.nombres}}" selected>{{personalesr.nombres}}</option>
                                                                                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                                                                                    </select>
                                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                                                                                                              <label for="email">Email de Contacto:</label>
                                                                                                              {% for personalesr in personales %}
                                                                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{personalesr.email}}" name="email" id="email" readonly>
                                                                                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                                            <div class="form-group" align="left">
                                                                                                              <label for="tel">Teléfonos de Contacto:</label>
                                                                                                              {% for personalesr in personales %}
                                                                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{personalesr.telefono}}" name="tel" id="tel" readonly>
                                                                                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                                                                              <!--<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfonos de Contacto" name="tel" required>-->
                                                                                                            </div>
```

Comment: Muestranos el código HTML que genera ese select, quizás así podamos sacar algo más en claro.

Comment: Acabé de editar la pregunta, ahora puse la mayor parte de mi código, revisa mi pregunta, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente tengas que hacer uso del método `$.each` para englobar todos los elementos que cumplen con tu selector:

```
$('#sautores').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
    $("#sautores option[name='"+nombres+"']").each(function(){
         if ($(this).prop("selected") == true) {
             alert("Si esta seleccionado");
         } else {
             alert("No esta seleccionado");
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: No me funciono amigo, ¿hay alguna otra forma?, ayudame por favor!